# Could not start RabbitMQ STOMP plugin?

Tags: centos, erlang, rabbitmq, message-queue, messagebroker

I've been trying to start the RabbitMQ server in CentOS 6 but unfortunately, it throws following error message when enabling STOMP plugin.

I am trying to run: RabbitMQ 3.6.0

I know that 61613 has been used. 
But I don't know how to change or configure it.

Is there some quick and dirty way to kill this and restart the server?
Of course, I don't want to disable the plugin.

```js
BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   {could_not_start,rabbitmq_stomp,
       {{undef,
            [{rabbit_networking,tcp_listener_spec,
                 [rabbit_stomp_listener_sup,
                  {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},61613,inet6},
                  [{backlog,128},{nodelay,true}],
                  ranch_tcp,rabbit_stomp_client_sup,
                  {stomp_configuration,"guest","guest",false,false},
                  stomp,"STOMP TCP Listener"],
                 []},
             {rabbit_stomp_sup,'-listener_specs/3-lc$^1/1-1-',4,
                 [{file,"src/rabbit_stomp_sup.erl"},{line,44}]},
             {rabbit_stomp_sup,init,1,
                 [{file,"src/rabbit_stomp_sup.erl"},{line,38}]},
             {supervisor,init,1,[{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,272}]},
             {gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,328}]},
             {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]},
        {rabbit_stomp,start,[normal,[]]}}}

{"init terminating in do_boot",{could_not_start,rabbitmq_stomp,{{undef,[{rabbit_networking,tcp_listener_spec,[rabbit_stomp_listener_sup,{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},61613,inet6},[{backlog,128},{nodelay,true}],ranch_tcp,rabbit_stomp_client_sup,{stomp_configuration,"guest","guest",false,false},stomp,"STOMP TCP Listener"],[]},{rabbit_stomp_sup,'-listener_specs/3-lc$^1/1-1-',4,[{file,"src/rabbit_stomp_sup.erl"},{line,44}]},{rabbit_stomp_sup,init,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_stomp_sup.erl"},{line,38}]},{supervisor,init,1,[{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,272}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,328}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]},{rabbit_stomp,start,[normal,[]]}}}}
```

According to rabbitmq-users group, this turned out to be a bug in the rabbitmq-server itself...so the fix for this is you can switch or

give 3.6.1.RC2 a try: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rabbitmq-users/RC2/rabbitmq-users/QmB-YLo89d0/U1GoGYpmAQAJ

I tried with 3.6.1.RC2 and it solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html

> edit your Configuration file, to contain a `tcp_listeners` variable for the `rabbitmq_stomp` application
>
> For example, a complete configuration file which changes the listener port to 12345 would look like:

```
[
  {rabbitmq_stomp, [{tcp_listeners, [12345]}]}
].
```

> while one which changes the listener to listen only on localhost (for both IPv4 and IPv6) would look like:

```
[
  {rabbitmq_stomp, [{tcp_listeners, [{"127.0.0.1", 61613},
                                     {"::1",       61613}]}]}
].
```

Comment: This answer does not help at all. I have tried several times changing the rabbitmq.config file with the above syntax but it throws the same error message.

Comment: Do you mean that you specify a different port and yet it still uses the default `61613` and throws an error? Can you post the content of your config file?

Comment: This is actually a bug in RabbitMQ-Server 3.6.0 with stomp enabled in CentOS 6.

Comment: If that's what it is then I suggest that you add an answer with links to the source of that information if available and tag it as the accepted answer to your question. That way whoever comes across your question will know the answer and you will get reputation points as well.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Amiramix (from this comment thread), I am answering my question.

In CentOS 6, I found a bug with STOMP plugin that throws the error stack as hinted in my question above. However, from the official rabbitmq contributors I got the response to try a newer version of rabbitmq-server.

So I tried with 3.6.1.RC2 and it solved this issues (in this version there are about 35 bug fixes and minor enhancements compared to 3.6.0)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rabbitmq-users/RC2/rabbitmq-users/QmB-YLo89d0/U1GoGYpmAQAJ

Latest rabbitmq-server releases, please try [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/tag/rabbitmq_v3_6_1_rc2)